# how to convert the scientific numbers to general

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template with 18 digit number column, when input that last numbers will be converting to zeros. so i modified the column to Text column. I need to conver the xls to csv, when converting i am validating the column if the number length is less than 18 i am padding the zeros to that number. After converting it to csv the numbers will be modifying as scientific numbers. is there any possibility to dont convert the numbers to scientific. it remains same in the text column.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see that behaviour (XL2007, Win XP)

Comment: After converting the xls to csv, then open the csv in excel it will display in scientific number like 2.0E5

Comment: So the problem is occuring when you open the file again in Excel, not during the CSV conversion?  If you open the CSV file in a text editor, what does it look like?

Comment: If we open in wordpad its looks normal number. After I reopen the file and delete some rows and save it. then the number format will be in scientific format. THe column should have the leading zeros or 18 numbers.

Comment: The text formatting you applied in excel is not preserved in the CSV file, so if you just open that CSV file in Excel you'll need to re-apply the formatting.  However, if you step through the text import wizard you can specifiy column formats when you re-open the file.

Comment: on opening the csv in excel, formatting it as text, still it shows the same format.

Comment: That's not what I see. You have to open the file via the text import wizard, and assign that column as "text"

Answer (score 0):

I was going to add this as a comment to follow on from the ones above but that option isn't appearing for me so I'll put it as an answer.

On the first point, Excel only allows you 15 significant digits which is why you were getting zeroes at the end originally. So yes, you do have to format the column as text to handle 18 digit inputs. As Tim Williams pointed out, though, while the formatting determines the content of the file that you SAVE (which is why you see the correct formatting when you open it in Wordpad) it doesn't help when you reopen it in Excel.

The problem is that Excel is so keen to "help" you that in most cases it won't display the text import wizard when you open a .csv file. It will instead open the file straight up, making its best guess about the content format and in your case, despite the presence of the leading zeroes, it will guess incorrectly.

One way around this is to save the file as a .csv but ensure that it has a different extension. I use .cma. When you save the file you save it as something like "MyFile.cma" but you DO have to enclose that name in double quotes in the File Name dialog, otherwise Excel will save it as MyFile.cma.csv

When you open a .cma (or some other unrecognised extension like that) Excel will display the text import wizard, which allows you (as Tim suggested) to specify that you want the column to be text when the file is opened. In that way it won't convert to a number, and more specifically a scientific number.

The other option is to reopen the file using the OpenText method in VBA:

```
    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:= _
    "C:\Users\YourName\Documents\Data\YourFile.cma", _
    Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, 
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
    Space:=False, Other:=False, 
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

It depends on how much effort you want or need to put into automating this.

Comment: Just by way of clarification as well... reformatting the column as text AFTER it has been opened in Excel will have no effect. (Which is what I suspect was happening from the "on opening the csv in excel, formatting it as text, still it shows the same format" comment.) It has to be formatted BEFORE it opens in Excel, either by using the text import wizard or the OpenText VBA method.